# How do I install a required package on IBM Bluemix when deploying a Meteor application from DevOps Services?

Tags: node.js, meteor, ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-watson

I hope there is an IBM Bluemix wizard watching that can answer this.

I have an application, written in Meteor, which I am trying to deploy to Bluemix.  The application contains this line:

`var AdmZip = Npm.require('adm-zip');`

which of course means that the application uses the **adm-zip** package to do stuff.  When I try to deploy the application via DevOps Services, it fails with this error:

```
ERR Error: Cannot find module 'adm-zip'
```

in the logs.  If I remove the *Npm.require* line, the application deploys fine, but of course doesn't work correctly because *adm-zip* is not there.

My *package.json* file contains, among other things, this entry:

```
  "dependencies": {
      "adm-zip": "*"
  },
```

which I believe should be sufficient to load the adm-zip package.  I've also tried specifying a Git URL for adm-zip but the results are the same.

Does anyone know what I have to do to get this application to deploy correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Meteor documentation the following line...

```
// import a global NPM package
var Spooky = Npm.require('spooky');
```

...tries to import a global NPM package (installed with the *-g* flag).

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) for Meteor that handles NPM integration.

Install this module with the following command:

```
$ meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

If you have correctly set up the package dependency in *package.json*, you can use the following to import and use the *spooky* package:

```
// This method loads NPM modules you've specified in the packages.json file.
var Spooky = Meteor.require('spooky');
```

Comment: Interesting - not sure how I missed that.  I do have adm-zip installed globally on my workstation, and everything works fine.  But if I change that line to `Meteor.require("adm-zip");` I get a different error: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'require'`

Comment: Looking again at the documentation, it appears you also need to use the following command to install the meteor NPM integration: $ meteor add meteorhacks:npm
Does it work if you do that?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was just trying to edit my last comment with that information.:-)  

I ran `meteor add meteorhacks:npm`, and replaced `Npm.require("adm-zip")` with `Meteor.npmRequire("adm-zip")` and that got rid of that last error.  It's working now - thanks! 

Edit:  I also added this to the generated packages.json file:

`{
"adm-zip": "0.4.7"  
}`

It didn't seem necessary locally but it works on the server.

Comment: Hurrah! Let me update the answer with that information and you can accept it as confirmed.